# Using $this when not in object context, when using call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, url-routing

I am having a hard time trying to figure the error in the code. There some similar issues on SO, but they did not help that much with my specific problem. I also googled every possible phrases regarding the error, yet still no joy. 
In `ProductCategoryController.php` I have:

```
namespace App\controllers\admin;


use App\classes\CSRFToken;
use App\classes\Request;
use App\classes\ValidateRequest;
use App\models\Category;

class ProductCategoryController
{
    public $table_name = 'categories';
    public $categories;
    public $links;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $obj = new Category();
        $total = Category::all()->count(); // total number of rows
        list($this->categories, $this->links) = paginate(3, $total, $this->table_name, $obj);
    }

    public function show() {
        return view('admin/products/categories',
            [
                'categories' => $this->categories,
                'links' => $this->links
            ]);
    }

}
```

I get error

```
using $this when not in object context
```

on line 27 where I assign `'categories' => $this->categories` and `'links' => $this->links`

When I try setting 'categories' and 'links' to an empty array, everything work fine as expected.

[image]

In the RouteDispatcher.php I have: 
[image]

Perhaps I may be missing something very obvious, any support with my problem is well appreciated.

Comment: How are you calling ProductCategoryController's show method?

Comment: Probably statically `ProductCategoryController::show()`

Comment: Stack in image suggests RouteDispatcher uses call_user_func_array, to call the controller's show method.  Would be good to see more of this code.

Comment: @Progrock I will attach now.

Comment: Please inline code, rather than images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your dispatcher, you are calling your controller's method statically.

In your code you test if your method is callable on a new instance.  And then don't go on to reuse that newly created instance when calling.  Instead you use the class and method name in call_user_func_array - and therefore call it statically, which results in your error.

Try and change your code to something more like this:

```
$controller = new $this->controller;
$method     = $this->method;

if(is_callable(array($controller, $method)))
    call_user_func_array(array($controller, $method), $params);
```

Or move the `new`:

```
if(is_callable(array($this->controller, $this->method)))
    call_user_func_array(
        array(new $this->controller, $this->method),
        $params
    );
```

Comment: You are a king @Progrock. Thank you so so very much. Thank you.